# CMake: Link an executable to multiple libraries (*.so)

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm new to building with CMake. I'm using Ubuntu and I have a .cpp file (say xyz.cpp located somewhere in ~/mydir) which links to three custom shared libraries (libA.so, libB.so & libC.so libraries). These three *.so files are located in `/usr/local/lib`.

I want to create a CMakeLists.txt to get this compiled. The below script throws errors like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(xyz VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

# Set C standard to C11
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCES src/xyz.cpp)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

#For the shared library:

target_link_libraries(libA -L/usr/local/lib/)
target_link_libraries(libB -L/usr/local/lib/)
target_link_libraries(libC -L/usr/local/lib/)

target_link_libraries(xyz libA libB libC )
add_executable(xyz src/xyz.cpp)
```

ERROR:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: (target_link_libraries):

   Cannot specify link libraries for target "libA" which is not built
   by this project.


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: 1) `target_link_libraries` should follow `add_executable`; 2) you don't need `target_link_libraries(libA...)` at all; 3) to add link directories, use `target_link_directories`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple important notes:

1. The first argument to [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) should be a valid CMake *target*, created by `add_library()` or `add_executable()`. Therefore, any `target_link_libraries()` call should be placed **after** the `add_executable()` call in your code.
2. You only need **one** call to `target_link_libraries()` to link all of your `*.so` libraries to the executable. The first three calls are unnecessary (and invalid because `libA`, `libB`, and `libC` are all undefined). You should provide the **full** path to each of these libraries to ensure that the correct library is used.
3. It is good practice to include the scoping argument in `target_*` calls, such as `target_link_libraries()`. This specifies whether the libraries are linked-to (`PRIVATE`), added to the link interface (`INTERFACE`), or both (`PUBLIC`). This distinction becomes more important as your CMake project grows to include more targets.

With these notes, and a few others commented below, your CMake file could look something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

# No need to specify C and CXX for LANGUAGES here, these are enabled by default!
project(xyz VERSION 1.0.0)

# Set C standard to C11
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCES src/xyz.cpp)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

# Define your executable target. You can pass in the SOURCES variable defined above.
add_executable(xyz ${SOURCES})

# Link the other libraries to your executable, using their full path.
# Note, the '-L' flag is not necessary.
target_link_libraries(xyz PRIVATE 
    /usr/local/lib/libA.so
    /usr/local/lib/libB.so
    /usr/local/lib/libC.so
)
```

Comment: If there are dependencies between the libraries, ex. `libB.so` depends on `libA.so`, does it matter what order they are listed in, or are there other steps you need to do?